# Comparison Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, comparison, set

I have 2 arrays (`A` and `B`) that contain similar data with some differences. I would like to return an array of objects that are only in `A` and another array of objects that are only in `B`. So far I have been thinking:

1. Brute force with some optimizations (this is trivial)
2. Sort the arrays and use a binary search.

What are my other options? Any languages/solutions are fair game.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could sort both arrays then do a linear scan through both arrays at the same time.  This would be an O(nlogn) algorithm for the sort and O(n) for the scan / building of the new arrays.

Answer (score 2):

I'd stuff array A's elements into a hash table, then iterate over array B doing lookups in the  hash table to efficiently determine which elements in B are also in A.  Then do the same with B's elements in a hash table while iterating over array A.  That would be O(N) throughout.

Comment: Hash tables tend to generate faster algorithms, but ones that usually occupies most memory. Good answer, by the way

Answer (score 1):

A lot of this is going to depend on what type of data you have.  You mention sorting, so I take it the elements are comparable.  With sets of size `m` and `n`, this will take `O(m lg m + n lg n)` to sort, and that will dominate.  (Asymptotically, it won't matter if you do binary search or walk both lists.  Walking both lists should be `O( m + n)`.)  Of course, if you are using data with a better sort algorithm available, such as integers with radix-sort, you should be able to get down to `O( m + n)`.

Using sets (as others are suggesting) implicitly suggests using hashing, which will definitely make your problem easier.  If you hash all the elements in A ( `O(m)` ) and store all the hashes in a hash set in memory, then hash B ( `O(n)` ) and detect where collisions may occur in the hash set.  This becomes a matter for optimization: you have to evaluate a classic speed-memory trade-off.  The larger your hash set, the quicker the collision-checks will be.  This will run in `O( m + n )`.

It's worth noting that you can prove that any algorithm that does what you ask will run in at least `m + n` time, since all the inputs need to be looked at.

Comment: @David: in comparing sorting versus hash table approaches you also need to consider 1) cost of hash function computation vs cost of comparison (optimized for the not-equals case) and 2) whether the hash function gives a good spread.

Comment: @Stephen absolutely!  I didn't want to get into those considerations because they tend to require assumptions about the inputs which we don't have.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Sets. They usually have a difference() method (or something like this) that returns exactly what u want. Simple as that. Once it's language-agnostic, how you create sets or transform the difference into an array is done using general methods.

```
Set A = createSetA();
Set B = createSetB();

Array onlyAElements = transformToArray(A.difference(B));
Array onlyBElements = transformToArray(B.difference(A));
```

Alternatively, you could sort both arrays, and get both difference arrays at the same time. Something like

```
int aIndex = 0;
int bIndex = 0;

Array aOnly = new Array();
Array bOnly = new Array();

while (aIndex != a.length || bIndex != b.length)
{
   if (A[aIndex] == B[bIndex]
   {
       aIndex++;
       bIndex++;
   }
   else if (A[aIndex] > B[bIndex])
   {
       aOnly.add(A[aIndex]);
       aIndex++;
   }
   else 
   {
       bOnly.add(B[bIndex]);
       bIndex++;
   }
}
```

You should keep in mind there's some mistakes on getting out of bounds. But the code is just to get the main idea.

Comment: Just what I was going to say. Here is Python's sets module for example, where you can use difference() or simply the "-" operator. http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html

Comment: I think he's looking for the algorithm, which is hidden. There are plenty of easy one-liners for this (think LINQ), but they really don't teach us anything and we have no idea what their efficiency is without reading documentation.

Comment: The two algorithms for sets that I know of are hash sets and tree sets. Google or SO search for those terms.

Comment: Agree about set, but the question did ask for an algorithm not a data structure.  Perhaps you could expand your answer to involve sets.

Comment: Well, the difference() method do all the stuff for you, usually in an efficient way. But I added some code anyway

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an implementation or algorithm beyond what's already been said but I thought I would leave this solution in c#/linq for anyone who might find this question and wants to do this:

```
    var a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    var b = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };

    int[] addedToA = a.Except(b);
    int[] missingFromA = b.Except(a);

    foreach (var i in addedToA)
    {
        Console.Write("{0} ", i);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    foreach (var i in missingFromA)
    {
        Console.Write("{0} ", i);
    }
```

This prints:

```
8 9 10
4 5
```